# Python GIL и virtaulenv

Tags: python, многопоточность, python-2.x, multiprocessing, virtualenv

Правильно ли я понимаю, что GIL для каждого окружения будет свой? Или же он будет всё-таки один на все окружения одной версии (2.7)?

Comment: GIL свой у каждого отдельного процесса, а окружения тут ни при чём

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интерпретатор можно запустить много раз, в каждом процессе интерпретатора будет свой GIL. Виртуальное окружение - это просто папка, куда вынесен интерпретатор и какой-то набор библиотек и утилит. Интерпретаторов из одного виртуального окружения можно запустить хоть сотню. Соответственно, cвой GIL будет в каждом отдельном процессе интерпретатора. Нет никакой взаимосвязи между количеством виртуальных окружений и количеством GIL.